# Why LoginPemissionMixin redirects to the wrong url

Tags: django, mixins

I make my project with Django.
I want to let only logged user to access URL.
When my class uses LoginRequiredMixin to redirect to login view, after successful login it redirects to URL "main".

views.py

```
class LoginView(FormView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = "tavern_app/login.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("main")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.user
        login(self.request, user)
        return super().form_valid(form)


class CreateSessionBaseView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = '/log-in/'

    def get(self, request):

        return render(request, "tavern_app/create_session_base.html")
```

urls.py

```
    path("log-in/", LoginView.as_view(), name="login"),
    path("create-session/", CreateSessionBaseView.as_view(), name="create-session-base"),
```

at this moment, when I enter CreateSessionBaseView as not logged user it redirects to log-in with URL:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/log-in/?next=/create-session/`

But after successful login it redirects to "main" as it's defined in LoginView.

I've tried to deal with it with redirect_field_name:

```
class CreateSessionBaseView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = 'login'
    redirect_field_name = 'redirect_to'

    def get(self, request):

        return render(request, "tavern_app/create_session_base.html")
```

it changes URL to

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/log-in/?redirect_to=/create-session/
```

but it seems like success_url from LoginView is still winning.

How to redirect it back to my "create-session-base" page. I still want my "login" view to redirect to "main" in other cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. So i resolved it by adding this to Login view :

```
redirect_to = self.request.GET.get('next', None)
        if redirect_to:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy("main"))
```

Now it looks like this

```
class LoginView(FormView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    template_name = "tavern_app/login.html"
    success_url = reverse_lazy("main")

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.user
        login(self.request, user)

        redirect_to = self.request.GET.get('next', None)
        if redirect_to:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_to)
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy("main"))

        return super().form_valid(form)


class CreateSessionBaseView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = 'login'

    def get(self, request):

        return render(request, "tavern_app/create_session_base.html")
```

Now if URL address has ?next it redirects to right view. Like here:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/log-in/?next=/create-session/
```

In other cases it redirects to "main" like here:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/log-in/
```